# why serialized persisted RDD is occupies less memory than deserialized persisted RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I read that when an RDD is persisted in memory with some sort of serialization (whether it is default Java serialization or something like Kryo serialization) it occupies less space in memory. My understanding of serialization is that it is just a way to convert a Java object in memory to series of bits, and the deserialization is really the **process** of bringing those bits into memory as an object. So I always think of deserialization as **bringing back** to memory as an obeject from series of bits. Because of this the term of storing something as deserialized data is confusing to me. For me storing (as series of bits) is serialization and retrieving is deserialization. So I am not really able to imagine what it means by storing something as deserialized data. And because of this I am also not able to understand why would a serialized form occupy less space in cache. It seems to me that there is more to de/serialization than just dumping objects and getting them back, but I don't know what, and would exactly like to understand just that. Is it because serialized format is some sort of compression format really? and deserialized format is without any compression? As far as I know in Java programming I never came across the concept of storing objects as deserialized format. When we refer to storing, any Java article immediately starts talking about serialization and deserialization it only talks in the context of reading and bringing it back as object.

Comment: Good question, but i see no answer regarding why serialized RDD takes less memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself figured out the answer, so thought of posting it as it may help someone who is in similar confusion.

The whole confusion of 'storing as deserialized object' is caused by the way in which it is explained in the particular book I was referring to.

Spark either caches an RDD in memory as a Java object as RDD is just another object of some class (some RDD class) or it writes it to disk, and when it writes to disk, it is serialized (in case of Java/Scala, default Java serialized is used and in case of Python, python's 'pickle' module is used in order to serialize it). So this is all there is to it. So whenever we are talking about 'deserialized' RDD we are always referring to RDDs in memory. They should have ideally called it non-serialized rather than deserialized, to avoid confusion, but anyways. And serialized RDDs always refer to what gets written (cached) to disk.

Comment: Serialization does not imply a storage medium. i.e. You might serialize an object in memory. Also see Spark Documentation:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Comment: How Serialized RDD occupies less space in memory?

Comment: Have a look at off-heap storage, which is a serialized storage in RAM